# Adding Querystring Parameter to GridView ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a gridview with a hyperlink in first column.  Upon clicking the hyperlink, the user is redirected to Vendor.aspx. Now, I need to pass the consumer id (of the clicked row) as a query string to the Vendor.aspx.

What is the best method to achieve it? Is there a way in which we can handle it using markup code only?

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdConsumers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                EnableViewState="True" >
                <Columns>

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ConsumerID" SortExpression="ConsumerID" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkConsumerID" href="Vendor.aspx" runat="server"><%# Eval("ConsumerID")%></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>



                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status" SortExpression="Status"></asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

**READINGS:**

1. [Set Gridview DataNavigateUrlFormatString Dynamically inside User Control(ASCX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469155/set-gridview-datanavigateurlformatstring-dynamically-inside-user-controlascx)
2. [How do I add "&Source" to DataNavigateUrlFormatString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949860/how-do-i-add-source-to-datanavigateurlformatstring)
3. [Select row in GridView with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605637/select-row-in-gridview-with-javascript)
4. [How to bind the URL of a GridView HyperLinkField when the bound value contains a colon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539667/how-to-bind-the-url-of-a-gridview-hyperlinkfield-when-the-bound-value-contains-a)
5. [asp.net gridview DataNavigateUrlFormatString from DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804488/asp-net-gridview-datanavigateurlformatstring-from-datasource)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `DataNavigateUrlFormatString`

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ConsumerID" DataTextField="ConsumerID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Vendor.aspx?id={0}" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

... it will spare you `Eval()` and the problem with single/double quotes when putting it inside your `href`.

You can substitute the `DataTextField` if you like - I just put the *ConsumerID* there to be consistent with your example.

Comment: Thanks. I used HyperLinkField  similar to BoundField and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your hyperlink in gridview in .aspx file like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkConsumerID" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("ConsumerID")%>' />
```

Then in code-behind create a RowDataBound event handler:

```
    protected void grdConsumers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) return;
    var hlnkhlnk = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("lnkConsumerID");
    if (hlnkhlnk != null)
    {
        hlnkhlnk.NavigateUrl = "Vendor.aspx" + "?Consumer   ID=" + hlnkhlnk.Text;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do same using at `Grid view Item Data Bound Event`

```
    protected void grdConsumers_ItemDataBound(object sender,DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            // Get your consumerId here     
            ((HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("Edit")).NavigateUrl = "Vendor.aspx?id=" + consumerId
        }
    }
```